# R: Remove rows if no follow-up value is found in specific range of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I'm trying to remove rows (subjects) of my dataframe in R, that do not have a value within a set of columns.

```
Subject     Baseline    Week 1      Week 2      Week 3        Week 4 
  1           50         51          50          51             51
  2           75         77          NA          NA             76
  3           66         NA          NA          NA             NA
```

So that in this example, Subject 3 is removed form the dataframe and Subject 2 remains, because it has as least one cell with value over the columns Week1:Week4

With `dataframe[complete.cases(dataframe[,3:6]),]` all rows with any `NA` are removed, which is not the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rowSums`:

```r
dataframe[rowSums(is.na(dataframe[3:6])) != 4,]

  Subject Baseline Week.1 Week.2 Week.3 Week.4
1       1       50     51     50     51     51
2       2       75     77     NA     NA     76
```

Or with `apply` + `all` + `is.na`:

```r
dataframe[apply(dataframe[3:6], 1, \(x) !all(is.na(x))), ]
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks! I was almost there, my other line was `dataframe[rowSums(is.na(dataframe[,3:6])) == 0,]` which had the same result initially.  +1